# How to minimize server load when parsing using scrapy?/How to ignore <body> and parse info only from <head>

Tags: scrapy

I collect statistics and all the information I need is in the `<head>` (script tag) of site.

It have massive `<body>`(about 5-10 kb per page) so can I dont parse it for less server load?

I would be glad if you recommend alternative optimizations to reduce the server load

## settings.py

CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32 DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0.33 now speed 180/per min(sometimes 200)

Comment: Anyone can put a minus instead of useful advice.

Comment: Sure, why not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrapy operates with entire response body only. 
This behaviour coded in scrapy core.

> `CONCURRENCY_REQUEST = 32`

Scrapy don't have `CONCURRENCY_REQUEST` setting. Did you mean `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` ?

> `DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0.33` now speed 180/per min(sometimes 200)

If you didn't specify `RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY` as `False` (default value`True`).
download delay will be a [random number](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/core/downloader/__init__.py#L38) between 0.5x to 1.5x of `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` setting.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction, I copied it from the forum and there was a mistake. Fixed.

Comment: Can you tell me please if the same body parts can be copied into a cache so that scrapy doesn't download full page every time?